# GraphQL & Relay Filtering UI

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

**THE PROMPT**

If you were to build Google Calendar using relay, how would you structure the GraphQL schema and the Relay containers/components to properly handle showing & hiding multiple calendars?

**THE ATTEMPT**

One might imagine a schema like this:

```
viewer {
  user {
    calendars(calendarIds: [String]) {
      edges,
        node {
          name,
          id,
          events(dates: [Date]) {
            ... edges, node, eventinfo...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, I can pull down all the calendars and all the events, or a specific calendar, or what have you.

Structuring the Relay Containers and components, I would imagine the following:

```
<CalendarView Container>
  <CalendarView>
    <WeekView> or <MonthView> or <Agenda> etc...
      <Event>
```

Such that the CalendarView relay container sets up the fragment requesting the calendars, and the `CalenderView` component uses `setVariables` to toggle the showing/hiding of that calendar in the view.

The problem that I'm encountering (and that's making my head spin) is that the `Day`/`Week`/`Month`/`Agenda` components are combinatorial views — that is, they require the data from all selected events.

**THE PLOT THICKENS**

Now, that sounds just fine — have the `CalendarView` set the calendarId variables and pass the resulting events down, right? Well... kind of. Now the fragment for `CalendarView` is constructed with a set of `calendarIds`, such that toggling one `calendar` on or off changes the entire tree of what is to be fetched.

**THE GOTCHA?**

As far as I can tell, relay sees each combination of `calendarIds` as an entirely different fetch. So, when I toggle on a new `id` it fetches *all* the events, even for those calendars I've already fetched.

Put code-wise:

```
fragment calendar(calendarIds: [1, 2]) { ... }
```

Is an *entirely* different fetch from:

```
fragment calendar(calendarIds: [1, 2, 3]) { ... }
```

This is ... bad. There can be a lot of events on those calendars and the over-fetching is a killer.

In theory, I could create a container per calendar, but then how would I combine the events on those calendars and pipe them into a common sub-component? The calendars can't be layered because events need to move around in reaction to other events, even those on separate calendars (shifting left/right to show them side-by-side).

Thoughts? My brain hurts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Put code-wise, `calendar(calendarIds: [1, 2])` is an entirely different query from `calendar(calendarIds: [1, 2, 3])`

Yup. GraphQL doesn't assign semantics to field arguments, so Relay (nor any other GraphQL client) doesn't know that the `calendarIds` arguments correspond to the ids of the results. This is a common enough use-case, though, that Relay supports a special `nodes(ids: [ID!])` root field (on the Query type) that is treated as you were expecting. To use it, implement a `nodes` field in your schema that returns results as an array whose order matches that of the input ids, with null entries for any results that couldn't be loaded. E.g. if the input ids are `[1,2,3]`, you'd return `[result1, result2, result3]`. When using this field, Relay will diff arguments arguments against previously fetched data (because it makes the assumption that the arguments of this particular field have a semantic meaning as ids).

Comment: is there documentation anywhere on the `nodes` root field? We implement a root node field via `graphql-relay` but I can't find anything on `nodes`.

Comment: Also, is a "plural identifying root field" similar to the above approach? It would seem to me that like a "plural identifying root field", using the `nodes` field would require objects with one-to-one mappings to the ids. Ideally, I'd be able to query using variables against a large set of object (events) that aren't nicely grouped by the input ids (input: [Array of 3 ids], output: [Array of n events]), but both approaches appear to necessitate the creation of some intermediary object (input: [Array of 3 ids], output: [Array of 3 objects that have events]).

Comment: The `nodes` field isn't documented, but it works as I described above. There is no need for intermediate result objects, ie you can do `node(ids: [array of 3 event ids])` and return `[array of 3 events]` - the event results just have to be in the same order as the args.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion here — this is super helpful. I suppose I could restructure things to request eventIds for a given calendarId, and then request events by event ids, but the ideal is to request a bunch of events for a given calendar. In which case, there's not a one-to-one mapping between calendarId and event.